# SQL Left Join (Between Condition)

Tags: sql-server-2005, left-join, between

Is it possible to use a BETWEEN statement as a condition for a LEFT JOIN?

```
SELECT Table_1.*, Table_2.*
FROM Table_1 LEFT JOIN Table_2
ON Table_1.value BETWEEN Table_2.Value_1 AND Table_2.Value_2
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is, but you need to specify a column name from `Table_1`, like so:

```
SELECT Table_1.*, Table_2.*
FROM Table_1 LEFT JOIN Table_2
ON Table_1.Value BETWEEN Table_2.Value_1 AND Table_2.Value_2
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I figured it out a while ago. My query doesn't return any error, but doesn't return any results either. The problem came from the dates I used for the between statement. I forgot to convert them to time. Silly me. Lol.

Comment: `ON Table_1 BETWEEN` didn't return any errors? Does either `Table_1` or `Table_2` also have a column called `Table_1`? If not, then an invalid column error (Msg 207) certainly should have been the result...

Comment: Sorry @Aaron my mistake. That should be Table_1.Value.